# How can I reolve unmet dependencies when installing ubuntu-sdk on ubuntu desktop 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, ubuntu-sdk

I am trying to install ubuntu-sdk on my ubuntu desktop 14.04 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

But I am getting this error
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But no luck please help.

Comment: I followed the other post it didn't help me I don't have any file inside the directory /var/log/dist-upgrade/ @heemayl

Comment: Thanks @SylvainPineau that solved my problem. But actually I don't know how did that solve my problem?

Comment: @Mohsem Ibrahim You have to learn about installation packages, dependencies and how package manager works in general. Ubuntu as Debian derivative is using d`pkg`/`apt` package manager. More info: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) and [debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html)